# Using the Facebook Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to experiment with the Facebook Graph API, using the Graph API Explorer. Specifically, I have a Facebook event (which is "Open Invite"), and I'd like to see what information I can pull regarding this event. For instance, attendees, RSVP-status, etc.

When I use the explorer, I first need to get an access token. The amount of information I can pull from Facebook depends on what permissions I "give myself" in this token. However, I'm a little uncomfortable as to what this actually implies:

- By generating a token, do I somehow "leave some doors open into my
  Facebook event/account"? Are there any security concerns here? Do
  these permissions expire automatically along with the token, after
  some time?
- If I go to "Extended Permissions", and check the "rsvp_event" box,
  the token dialog tells me the "Graph API Explorer would like to
  manage your events". I guess this is fine, in fact that this is
  specifically what I'm asking for, but is this "safe" to do?

Since this is an upcoming event, I have to be 100% certain I won't somehow end up messing up the actual event, like removing people or even deleting the event. Perhaps the Graph API Explorer can only **pull** information about the event, or can I accidentally edit/delete the event through the same tool?

Sorry for the vague question, but perhaps someone can shed some light on these things?

Comment: Token is bound to the GAE app, so until you leak it nothing bad will happen (unless you do it yourself). And for your “100% certainty”, create a test event and use that to play with instead of the original one.

Answer (score 1):

The GraphExplorer can also post/edit and delete data. On the left hand site you have a drop down menu with GET/POST/DELETE if you stay with get u can't modify any data.

As to the security concerns if the Token expires the permission expire and you can also remove the permissions manually by clicking on `Get Acces Token` and then `Clear`.

Comment: These are good remarks, thanks :)
I guess, leaving the drop-down on GET *should* prevent any damage (read only). Good idea with the test event, though! I could simply have some friends RSVP to it, to generate some test-data.